# Nuget add custom variables into .nuspec file compatible to XSD scheme

Tags: cmake, nuget, nuspec

NuGet obtains packages from our own gallery server. A script then creates a CMAKE script with global variables for each package location. I want to add package specific variables like BOOST_INCLUDEDIR or BOOST_LIBRARYPATH with package relative pathes into the .nuspec file of the package. However, all variables shall be usable in CMAKE later.

The .nuspec xsd schema does not allow additional properties. Is there another solution ?

Here is an example of what I need:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>boost_x86_src</id>
    <version>1.55.0</version>
    <authors>Fabian Stern</authors>
    <owners>Fabian Stern</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Test Package</description>
    <dependencies />
    <frameworkAssemblies />
    <references>
      <reference file="signature.sig" />
    </references>
    <properties>
        <add key="BOOST_INCLUDEDIR" value="include/win32" />
        <add key="BOOST_LIBRARYPATH" value="libs/win32" />
    </properties>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: We have a workaround: We use CMAKE to extract a globals.cmake from the .nupkg which will set the neccessary environment variables.